# Kotlin max() Function Type Mismatch Required: Boolean Found: Int Problem

Tags: algorithm, kotlin, max

I am trying to solve an algorithm for finding max subarray in an array, using the max() function that compares 2 Ints and returns the bigger value.

I looked at other questions on stack overflow and no one refers to this problem so I must be doing something very basic wrong here. Also looked at the .math Library on Kotlin:

[https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/max.html#:~:text=Returns%20the%20greater%20of%20two,then%20the%20result%20is%20NaN%20.&text=Returns%20the%20greater%20of%20two%20values.,-Common](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/max.html#:%7E:text=Returns%20the%20greater%20of%20two,then%20the%20result%20is%20NaN%20.&text=Returns%20the%20greater%20of%20two%20values.,-Common)

To try and understand but again, I put two Ints in a max() function and I keep getting type mismatch as it requires a Boolean.

I even went and created my own function (maxCustom()) in the code below to try and bypass that, stating specifically that it receives two Ints and returns an Int, and I still get the same Boolean type mismatch.

```
fun maximumSubarray(nums: List<Int>): Int {

    fun maxCustom(a: Int, b: Int): Int {
        return if (a > b) a
        else b
    }

    var maxGlobal = 0
    var maxCurrent = maxGlobal == nums[0]

    for (num in nums[1] .. nums[nums.size-1]) {
        maxCurrent = maxCustom(a = nums[num], b = maxCurrent + nums[num])

        if (maxCurrent > maxGlobal) {
            maxGlobal = maxCurrent
        }
    }


    return maxGlobal

}


fun main() {
    val nums = listOf(-2, 3, 2, -1)
    val solution = maximumSubarray(nums)
    println(solution)
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is `var maxCurrent = maxGlobal == nums[0]` supposed to do? That's where the Boolean is coming from.

Comment: I see, should I just create two separate vars like so:

    var maxGlobal = nums[0]
    var maxCurrent = nums[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sam points out, your `maxCurrent` variable is a Boolean, not an Integer. As such, when you try to assign an Integer to `maxCurrent`, it fails.

To avoid such errors in the future, you should instantiate your variables with types using syntax such as `var maxCurrent: Int = maxGlobal`.

N.B.: For this particular problem it would be better to instantiate your `maxGlobal` with a declaration such as `var maxGlobal: Int = Int.MIN_VALUE`. This is the minimum value an Int can have. You should do this as the maximum subarray could be less than 0!

Comment: First of all thank you, that does work and makes complete sense.

Also, in this specific case should I instantiate both vars to the first Int in the array like so:

    var maxGlobal = nums[0]
    var maxCurrent = nums[0]

Or should I still instantiate to Int.MIN_VALUE ?

Comment: Being more strictly correct, you could instantiate `var maxGlobal: Int = nums.minOrNull()` since the minimum `maxGlobal` could be is the single smallest element of the input. Then, you can instantiate `var maxCurrent: Int = maxGlobal` to avoid restating yourself.